# Does meta http-equiv can direct download?

Tags: html, meta

When I go to the page the Image will start download auto.
And the page had different html.
I am trying with this

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=LINK/pic.png">
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. Have you tried running the code? Does it do what you expect? Does it do something you don't expect?

Comment: yes, The page go to the link of picture, But I want the picture download directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

A meta redirect cannot simulate the effects of a `download` attribute on a link or a `Content-Disposition: Attachment` HTTP response header.

Comment: Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @TamalDev — a Content-Disposition: Attachment HTTP response header

Comment: That **is** an example. [Search engines are cool](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Content-Disposition%3A+Attachment&t=hg&ia=web).

Comment: Done.Thanks a lot.